# Weird Pokemon hatching background

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I'm playing Pokemon Omega Ruby and hatched a Meowth.  The Pokemon glittered when it came out of the egg, and it had a sort of yellow background with orange dots, but the Meowth is definitely not shiny.  I haven't found any indication of what that was about by searching online.  Can somebody point out what it is that I'm missing here?

Comment: Do you have an image to show us?

Comment: I'm afraid not.  The best I can do is describe it.  I say the Pokemon glittered, but in truth, it looked more like the glitter was all in the foreground.  The Meowth in question has a brown tail and feet so I know it's not shiny.  They'd be pink otherwise.

Comment: And the Pokemon looks fine in the Summary screen? No weird markings or anything there?

Comment: Yeah, I went and checked in the summary screen because I thought maybe it actually was a shiny and just didn't show it for whatever reason.  Just a regular, ol' Meowth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's completely normal. The background and hatch effect was changed a bit from XY's but every egg in ORAS (even shiny ones) will hatch with that yellow and orange polkadot background and have sparkly effects.

The only way to tell if your newly hatched pokemon is shiny is to look at its colors, or just wait and look for the red star on its summary screen later.

Comment: Thanks.  It just threw me off, I guess, since that was the first one I'd done in ORAS.